# Java Number Format Exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, numberformatexception

I was solving aquestion on `CodeChef` platform when I faced a `NumberFormatException`.

First I used `Scanner` for handling the inputs, then `BufferedReader`. But none of them worked!

### Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Practise {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        while(t > 0) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 0;

            while(i < s.length()) {
                String temp = "";
                while(s.charAt(i) != ' '){
                    temp += s.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    if(i >= s.length()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                al.add(temp);
                i++;
            }

            if(al.contains("not")) {
                System.out.println("Real Fancy");
            } else {
                System.out.println("regularly Fancy");
            }

            t--;
        } 
    }
}
```

What could the problem be?

*Input*
-->The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number 
   of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
-->The first and only line of each test case contains a single string S denoting 
   a quote.

The Exception message i am getting-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Practise.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: `int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());` make sure the value of `br.readLine()` is pure number

Comment: t is an integer from 1 to 50 and it is passing all the custom test cases

Comment: use debugger, stop just before the line which exception is thrown and see the `br.readLine()` value, then probably you'll see that is not a just a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation:

```
* Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert
* a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not
* have the appropriate format.
```

The exception will be thrown at the line `int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`. The reason why the exception will be thrown there is that the input that you read there isn't a Number. If it is a number + a String or something else it will throw the `NumberFormatException`.

Example input `1235a`

This will throw an exception with the following message:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1235a"

So you should debug what the input there is.

Comment: Input:
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first and only line of each test case contains a single string S denoting a quote.

Comment: From the exception you get the message that your input is `null` that means that there is no input was given. That causes your exception.